# How do I return a json surrounded by {} instead of [] on Node.js(express) returning a result of a query using knex and postgresql

Tags: json, node.js, express, knex.js

if I do a curl request to my node.js(EXPRESS) API curl `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/events/user/id/1`  I get this result:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"casamiento 1","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000805BC00000000000003E40"},{"id":"2","name":"casamiento 2","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio 2","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000405BC00000000000003D40"},{"id":"3","name":"fiesta del sandwich de miga","description":"Nos juntamos a comer sandwiches de miga hasta reventar","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E610000000000000000000000000000000804840"}]
```

and I need the output to be surrounded by curly brackets like:

```
 {{"id":"1","name":"casamiento 1","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000805BC00000000000003E40"},{"id":"2","name":"casamiento 2","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio 2","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000405BC00000000000003D40"},{"id":"3","name":"fiesta del sandwich de miga","description":"Nos juntamos a comer sandwiches de miga hasta reventar","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E610000000000000000000000000000000804840"}}
```

My model "event" file is like this which makes the query to knex and then return the results:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/flock';
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: connectionString,
  searchPath: 'knex,public'
});

//Get all events from a particular user
exports.getUserEvents=function(id_user){



    console.log("Retrieving data from id_user: "+id_user);

    var promise1 = Promise.try(function () {
    return knex('events')
      .select('*')
      .where('user_id', id_user);
     });

    var promise2=promise1.then(function (rows) { // this creates a new promise, and the promise created here is what gets returned to the caller
      console.log('Returning '+rows.length+' rows from the user with id '+id_user);
      return rows;

    });

    return promise2;
}
```

and my router  file, which calls the model file function getUserEvents, is like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Event=require('../models/event');


//get all events from a user

router.get('/user/id/:id_user', function(req, res, next) {

   var id_user= req.params.id_user;

   var promise = Event.getUserEvents(id_user);

    promise.then(function (result) {
     console.log('Sending response');
     return res.json(result);  //<---this line builds the JSON response
   });

   promise.catch(function (err) {


     return res.sendStatus(500); 

   });

});




module.exports = router
```

My question is, How do I send the json object list surrounded by {} and not by [] like is returning now?. Thank you very much

**EDIT: This solved my problem, the final format is {"rows":[{row1},{row2},etc]}**

```
exports.getUserEvents=function(id_user){



    console.log("Retrieving data from id_user: "+id_user);

    var promise1 = Promise.try(function () {
    return knex('events')
      .select('*')
      .where('user_id', id_user);
     });

    var promise2=promise1.then(function (rows) { // this creates a new promise, and the promise created here is what gets returned to the caller
      console.log('Returning '+rows.length+' events from the user with id '+id_user);
      return {rows};//<----This solved the issue

    });

    return promise2; }
```

Comment: Why do you need that exact output (that is not valid)? Could you also answer what you are going to give that output to? Why is an array [{},{}], or an array-looking object {1:{},2:{}} not apropiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api request is returning an array of objects

```
arrayOfObjects = [
    {objkey: objvalue},
    {objkey: objvalue}
]
```

You could nest the array in an object like this

```
newObj = {
    nestedarray: result
}
```

Or you could return the objects as individual values

```
newObj = {
    1: result[0],
    2: result[1],
    3: result[2]
}
```

But all objects need a key value pair.

Note that an Array in Javascript is actually a specialised type of object that still uses property names that happen to be integers, but are optimised to allow specialised methods.

So in your case:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Event=require('../models/event');


//get all events from a user

router.get('/user/id/:id_user', function(req, res, next) {

    var id_user= req.params.id_user;

    var promise = Event.getUserEvents(id_user);

    promise.then(function (result) {
    console.log('Sending response');

    // Option One
    var newObj = {
        nestedarray: result
    }

    // Option Two
    var newObj = {}
    response.forEach(function(elem, index) {
        newObj[index] = elem;
    });

    return res.json(newObj);  //<---this line builds the JSON response
});

   promise.catch(function (err) {

        return res.sendStatus(500); 

   });
});
```

Note that in both options you do not end up with the format you want simply because it is not possible, but either option gets rid of the array syntax.

Comment: Thank you, but could you give some code specifications of how to do this in this particular case?....I understand what you are saying, but I need to know the implementation, not the theoretical side of the matter....Cause I'm using this knex library for queries to postgres DB and I don't know how to return things in that format....I just want the {{object1},{object2},{object3}} format

Comment: I mean, I don'twant the format  

{  [
      {object1},
      {object2}
   ]
}

which is what you are proposing by wrapping it up with {}....just

{{},{},{} }

Comment: Option two gives you an object: {1:{}, 2:{}...}

Comment: I don't want to add that index...I just want the object itself as it is.....

{{"name":name, "last_name":"last_name"},{"name":name, "last_name":"last_name"}}

that format....the thing is that I don't have much control over building the object cause knex returns it like that......how can I achieve that exact format?

Comment: All objects require a key value pair. What you are asking is not possible in either javascript or using JSON. I was attempting to provide an alternative. From http://www.json.org/ JSON is built on two structures:

A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that was it was not possible, thank you, answer accepted....I ended up wrapping the answer between {} and it worked wonders.....The final format was {"result":[{o1 },{o2},{o3}]}....I added


return {rows};  in the event model when returning the query results

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you want to process every object individually you can use:

```
for (i in result){
  console.log(result[i]);
}
```

that would return, for the example you provided:

```
{"id":"1","name":"casamiento 1","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000805BC00000000000003E40"}
and
{"id":"2","name":"casamiento 2","description":"el casamiento del tio claudio 2","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:57.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:14:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E61000000000000000405BC00000000000003D40"}
and
{"id":"3","name":"fiesta del sandwich de miga","description":"Nos juntamos a comer sandwiches de miga hasta reventar","mode_id":1,"initial_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","end_date":"2016-05-28T22:15:58.000Z","state_id":1,"user_id":"1","location":"0101000020E610000000000000000000000000000000804840"}
```

Note: {{stuff: 1}}, as you proposed as wanted output, is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON the `[]` brackets surround arrays.  Your query returns an array, and in your line `return res.json(result)` the result variable is an array.  Make it return a single object instead of an array and the `[]` will go away.  If you're expecting your query to contain multiple results and still don't want an array, wrap the array in another object like `{newResult: result}` and return that instead.

Comment: thank you, you answer was helpful too but Alexi2 tried to aware me that  what I wanted was not possible and gave valid alternatives so I will accept his answer, but I ended up doing this.......Thank you very much!!